# How to simplify output of Series?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, series-expansion, recursion, difference-equations

The command

```
Series[Sum[Sum[1/(a*b), {b, a, 3 a}], {a, 1, N/Sqrt[3]},  Assumptions -> N > 0], {N, Infinity, 1}]
```

produces a somewhat complicated answer

```
(
SeriesData[N, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {
   Rational[1, 12] (
     6 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 + Rational[-3, 2] Log[3]^2 - 6 Log[3] Log[
      N^(-1)] - 6 Log[N^(-1)]^2), 
    Rational[
     1, 4] ((-2) 3^Rational[1, 2] + 3^Rational[1, 2] Log[
       3] + 2 3^Rational[1, 2] Log[N^(-1)])}, 0, 2, 1]) + 
 DifferenceRoot[
   Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {-\[FormalN] (1 + \[FormalN]) \
(1 + 3 \[FormalN]) (2 + 3 \[FormalN]) (74 + 90 \[FormalN] + 
          27 \[FormalN]^2) \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (588 + 
          3984 \[FormalN] + 10857 \[FormalN]^2 + 15291 \[FormalN]^3 + 
          11718 \[FormalN]^4 + 4617 \[FormalN]^5 + 
          729 \[FormalN]^6) \[FormalY][
         1 + \[FormalN]] + (-1468 - 8784 \[FormalN] - 
          20595 \[FormalN]^2 - 24588 \[FormalN]^3 - 
          15930 \[FormalN]^4 - 5346 \[FormalN]^5 - 
          729 \[FormalN]^6) \[FormalY][
         2 + \[FormalN]] + (2 + \[FormalN])^2 (4 + 3 \[FormalN]) (5 + 
          3 \[FormalN]) (11 + 36 \[FormalN] + 
          27 \[FormalN]^2) \[FormalY][3 + \[FormalN]] == 
      0, \[FormalY][1] == 0, \[FormalY][2] == 
      1/6 (11 - 6 EulerGamma), \[FormalY][3] == 
      1/6 (11 - 6 EulerGamma) + 
       1/240 (85 + 19 (11 - 6 EulerGamma) - 6 EulerGamma)}]][
  1/3 (3 + Sqrt[3] N)]
```

How to simplify it as far as it is possible? BTW, this is a serious math question asked at MathOverflow, not art for art's sake.

Comment: Doesn't `N/Sqrt[3]` need to be an integer ?

Comment: @ b.gatessucks : Thank you for your attention. No, this is not necessary.

Comment: Then how do you compute the outer sum over `a`...? How many terms are in the sum? Also, avoid using capital letters like `N`, many of them are reserved _Mathematica_ symbols.

Comment: Think of Sum[j, {j, 1, 3.5}]  and Sum[j, {j, a, 3.5 a}].

Comment: You can write the sum as `Series[Sum[1/(a*b), {a, 1, n/Sqrt[3]}, {b, a, 3 a}, 
  Assumptions -> n > 0], {n, Infinity, 1}]`, but this doesn't simplify it. Answer removed, I switched out the order.

Comment: `N` is definately a reserved symbol, don't use it. I cant test here, but what do you get without that `Sqrt@3` (and something besides `N`)?

Comment: link to mathoverflow question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/249672/asymptotic-estimate-of-double-summation/250154#250154

Comment: @ george2079 : The same result with n instead of N. I followed the notation of the question at MathOverflow.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't look as if applying `Series` does anything useful.  It doesn't (for example) indicate which of the terms is growing fastest.

Comment: @ mikado : The question was asked because of this reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can split out the `DifferenceRoot` part and recompute as a recurrence. Because it is linear it will give an explicit solution albeit in terms of `RootSum`. I use `Normal` to force an explicit sum.

```
ss2 = RSolveValue[{-n (1 + n) (1 + 3 n) (2 + 3 n) (74 + 90 n + 
         27 n^2) y[
        n] + (588 + 3984 n + 10857 n^2 + 15291 n^3 + 11718 n^4 + 
         4617 n^5 + 729 n^6) y[
        1 + n] + (-1468 - 8784 n - 20595 n^2 - 24588 n^3 - 
         15930 n^4 - 5346 n^5 - 729 n^6) y[
        2 + n] + (2 + n)^2 (4 + 3 n) (5 + 3 n) (11 + 36 n + 27 n^2) y[
        3 + n] == 0, y[1] == 0, y[2] == 1/6 (11 - 6 EulerGamma), 
    y[3] == 1/6 (11 - 6 EulerGamma) + 
      1/240 (85 + 19 (11 - 6 EulerGamma) - 6 EulerGamma)}, y[n], n];
ss2b = Normal[ss2];
```

Now we compute the series. If I cut and pasted my inputs correctly, it should be as below.

```
Series[
 ss2b + (6 EulerGamma^2 + \[Pi]^2 - 6 PolyGamma[0, 1 + n/Sqrt[3]]^2 - 
     6 PolyGamma[1, 1 + n/Sqrt[3]])/12, {n, Infinity, 2}, 
 Assumptions -> n > 1000]

(* Out[426]= (SeriesData[n, 
    Infinity, {(-9*(72*EulerGamma - 60*EulerGamma^2 + 10*Pi^2 - 
          15*Log[3]^2 - 72*Log[n^(-1)] + 
                  120*EulerGamma*Log[n^(-1)] - 
          60*Log[3]*Log[n^(-1)] - 60*Log[n^(-1)]^2 + 
          148*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 1/3] - 
                  148*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 1/3] + 
          148*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 2/3] - 
          148*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 2/3] - 
                  588*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
          120*EulerGamma^2*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] - 
          20*Pi^2*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
                  30*Log[3]^2*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
          588*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] - 
          240*EulerGamma*Log[n^(-1)]*
                    PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
          120*Log[3]*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
          120*Log[n^(-1)]^2*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] - 
                  588*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
          120*EulerGamma^2*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] - 
          20*Pi^2*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
                  30*Log[3]^2*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
          588*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] - 
          240*EulerGamma*Log[n^(-1)]*
                    PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
          120*Log[3]*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
          120*Log[n^(-1)]^2*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
                  440*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
          120*EulerGamma^2*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] + 
          20*Pi^2*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
                  30*Log[3]^2*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
          440*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] + 
          240*EulerGamma*Log[n^(-1)]*
                    PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
          120*Log[3]*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
          120*Log[n^(-1)]^2*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] + 
                  440*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
          120*EulerGamma^2*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] + 
          20*Pi^2*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
                  30*Log[3]^2*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
          440*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] + 
          240*EulerGamma*Log[n^(-1)]*
                    PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
          120*Log[3]*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
          120*Log[n^(-1)]^2*PolyGamma[0, 8/3]))/4, 
          (9*(18 + 30*Sqrt[3] - 30*EulerGamma - 15*Sqrt[3]*Log[3] - 
          30*Sqrt[3]*Log[n^(-1)] + 37*PolyGamma[0, 1/3] + 
                  37*PolyGamma[0, 2/3] - 147*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] - 
          60*Sqrt[3]*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
                  60*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
          30*Sqrt[3]*Log[3]*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
                  60*Sqrt[3]*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] - 
          147*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] - 60*Sqrt[3]*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
                  60*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
          30*Sqrt[3]*Log[3]*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
                  60*Sqrt[3]*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
          110*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] + 60*Sqrt[3]*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
                  60*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
          30*Sqrt[3]*Log[3]*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
                  60*Sqrt[3]*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] + 
          110*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] + 60*Sqrt[3]*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
                  60*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
          30*Sqrt[3]*Log[3]*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
                  60*Sqrt[3]*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 8/3]))/2, 
          (-3*(117 + 30*EulerGamma - 45*Log[3] - 90*Log[n^(-1)] - 
          37*PolyGamma[0, 1/3] - 37*PolyGamma[0, 2/3] - 
                  123*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] - 
          60*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
          90*Log[3]*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 
                  180*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] - 
          123*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] - 60*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
                  90*Log[3]*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
          180*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] + 
          160*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] + 
                  60*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
          90*Log[3]*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 
          180*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] + 
                  160*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] + 
          60*EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
          90*Log[3]*PolyGamma[0, 8/3] - 
                  180*Log[n^(-1)]*PolyGamma[0, 8/3]))/4}, 0, 3, 1] - 
      407*
    Sum[(1/(11*K[1]))*(9*(EulerGamma - PolyGamma[0, 1/3] - 
          PolyGamma[0, 2/3] + PolyGamma[0, 1/3 + K[1]] + 
                  PolyGamma[0, 2/3 + K[1]] + 
          PolyGamma[0, 1 + K[1]])), {K[1], 1, -1 + n}])/
   (270*(-1 + 2*PolyGamma[0, 4/3] + 2*PolyGamma[0, 5/3] - 
     2*PolyGamma[0, 7/3] - 2*PolyGamma[0, 8/3])) *)
```

Not exactly simpler, but more what one would regard as "explicit". I'm guessing that is closer to what is wanted, even if it is not particularly simple. Note that there is an unevaluated `Sum`, so perhaps it is going to be difficult to come up with a fully elementary result.

Well, actually we can get a handle on that `Sum` as well, although showing this to be correct requires error estimates outside my reach at the moment. Specifically, we can extract a series for that summand and sum that instead (not done: is the tail going to shrink in a way that justifies this approximation).

```
ss3 = 
 Sum[PowerExpand[
   Normal[Series[(1/(11*K[1]))*(9*(EulerGamma - PolyGamma[0, 1/3] - 
          PolyGamma[0, 2/3] + PolyGamma[0, 1/3 + K[1]] + 
                  PolyGamma[0, 2/3 + K[1]] + 
          PolyGamma[0, 1 + K[1]])), {K[1], Infinity, 2}]]], {K[1], 
   1, -1 + n}, Assumptions -> n > 1000]

(* Out[439]= 9/22 (2 EulerGamma HarmonicNumber[-1 + n] + 
   HarmonicNumber[-1 + n, 2] - 
   2 HarmonicNumber[-1 + n] PolyGamma[0, 1/3] - 
   2 HarmonicNumber[-1 + n] PolyGamma[0, 2/3] + 6 StieltjesGamma[1] - 
   6 StieltjesGamma[1, n]) *)
```

This can be expanded into a series in `n` at `Infinity`.

```
Series[ss3, {n, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> n > 1000]

(* Out[440]= 1/11 ((
SeriesData[n, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {
     Rational[3, 4] (
       12 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 - 12 EulerGamma Log[
        n^(-1)] - 12 EulerGamma PolyGamma[0, 
Rational[1, 3]] + 12 Log[n^(-1)] PolyGamma[0, 
Rational[1, 3]] - 12 EulerGamma PolyGamma[0, 
Rational[2, 3]] + 12 Log[n^(-1)] PolyGamma[0, 
Rational[2, 3]] + 36 StieltjesGamma[1]), 
      Rational[9, 2] (-1 - EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 
Rational[1, 3]] + PolyGamma[0, 
Rational[2, 3]]), Rational[3, 4] (-3 - EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 
Rational[1, 3]] + PolyGamma[0, 
Rational[2, 3]])}, 0, 3, 1]) - 27 StieltjesGamma[1, n]) *)
```

Comment: @ Daniel Lichtblau : I am grateful to you for your attempt to solve the difficult problem under consideration. You have succeeded in getting rid of  DifferenceRoot. However, the aim is to obtain something like Log[3]*Log[N] + Log[3]*Log[Sqrt[3]/3] + Pi^2/18 + 
 Sum[(PolyGamma[a + 2/3] + PolyGamma[a + 1/3] - 
     2 PolyGamma[a])/(3 a), {a, 1, Infinity}] + Log[3]*EulerGamma . There is reason to believe this is true.

Answer (score 2):

An answer similar to the [second answer in MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/250154/98683) can be obtained with Mathematica as follows.  With `N/Sqrt[3]` represented by `p` for convenience, compute

```
f = Sum[Sum[1/(a*b), {b, a, 3 a}], {a, 1, p] // Expand;
```

Then, extract the portion of `f` involving `DifferenceRoot`, convert it to a recurrence relation, and `RSolve` it.

```
First@FullSimplify[y[p] /. RSolve[First[Head[f[[-1]]]][y, p], y[p], p]]
    /. K[1] -> m /. p -> p + 1

(* -(EulerGamma*(EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 1 + p])) + 
   (11*Sum[(9*(RootSum[2 + 11*#1 + 18*#1^2 + 9*#1^3 & , PolyGamma[0, m - #1] & ] - 
  RootSum[2 + 11*#1 + 18*#1^2 + 9*#1^3 & , PolyGamma[0, -#1] & ]))/(11*m), {m, 1, p}])/27*)
```

Now, apply `Normal` to `RootSum` and combine the result with the rest of `f`.

```
% /. RootSum[z1_, z2_] :> Normal[RootSum[z1, z2]];
f2 = Simplify[f1 + f[[1 ;; -2]]] // Expand

(* -EulerGamma^2/2 + Pi^2/12 - EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 1 + p] - PolyGamma[0, 1 + p]^2/2 - 
  PolyGamma[1, 1 + p]/2 + (11*Sum[(9*(EulerGamma - PolyGamma[0, 1/3] - PolyGamma[0, 2/3] + 
   PolyGamma[0, 1/3 + m] + PolyGamma[0, 2/3 + m] + PolyGamma[0, 1 + m]))/(11*m), 
   {m, 1, p}])/27 *)
```

Next, group the terms in the `Sum` into three `Sum`s (by hand) as follows.

```
f3 = (f2[[1 ;; -2]] + 
    (Sum[(-2 EulerGamma - PolyGamma[0, 1/3] - PolyGamma[0, 2/3])/m, {m, 1, p}] + 
     Sum[(3 PolyGamma[0, 1 + m] + 3 EulerGamma)/m, {m, 1, p}] + 
     Sum[(PolyGamma[0, 1/3 + m] + PolyGamma[0, 2/3 + m] - 2 PolyGamma[0, 1 + m])/m, 
     {m, 1, p}])/3) // Simplify // Expand
```

The point of this manipulation is to gather together terms that Mathematica can `Sum`, leaving the terms involving `PolyGamma[0, 1/3 + m] + PolyGamma[0, 2/3 + m]`, which Mathematica cannot `Sum` symbolically, to be approximately cancelled by the term `-2 PolyGamma[0, 1 + m]` in the final `Sum`.

```
(* -EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2/6 + (EulerGamma*HarmonicNumber[p])/3 - 
   (HarmonicNumber[p]*PolyGamma[0, 1/3])/3 - (HarmonicNumber[p]*PolyGamma[0, 2/3])/3 - 
   EulerGamma*PolyGamma[0, 1 + p] - PolyGamma[1, 1 + p] + 
   Sum[(PolyGamma[0, 1/3 + m] + PolyGamma[0, 2/3 + m] - 2*PolyGamma[0, 1 + m])/m,
   {m, 1, p}]/3 *)
```

The asymptotic expression for all but the final `Sum` in `f3` is given by

```
((Series[f3[[1 ;; -2]], {p, Infinity, 1}] // Normal) /. 
    p -> n/Sqrt[3]) // FunctionExpand // Simplify 

(* (3 Sqrt[3] (-2 + Log[3]) + n (π^2 + 6 EulerGamma Log[3] - 3 Log[3]^2) - 
    6 n Log[3] Log[1/n])/(6 n) *)
```

Its numerical value is `1.6756 - 0.780625/n + 1.09861 Log[n]`.

Because the remaining `Sum` converges rapidly, its upper limit can be replaced by `Infinity` to yield

```
f3[[-1]] /. Sum -> NSum /. p -> Infinity

(* -0.465567 *)
```

or for the entire expression, `1.21003 - 0.780625/n + 1.09861 Log[n]`

**Alternative, Simpler Derivation**

Two identities permit a much simpler derivation.

```
FullSimplify[PolyGamma[0, z] == PolyGamma[0, z + 1] - 1/z]
(* True *)
FullSimplify[PolyGamma[0, z] == (1/3) Sum[PolyGamma[z/3 + k/3], {k, 0, 2}] + Log[3]]
    (* True *)
```

Begin by evaluating the inner `Sum` from the first line of code in the question.

```
Sum[1/(a*b), {b, a, 3 a}] // Expand
(* -(PolyGamma[0, a]/a) + PolyGamma[0, 1 + 3 a]/a *)
```

Apply the first identity to the `First` term, and the second to the `Last` term.

```
Simplify[(First[%] /. PolyGamma[0, z_] :> PolyGamma[0, z + 1] - 1/z) + 
    (Last[%] /.  PolyGamma[0, z_] :> (1/3) Sum[PolyGamma[z/3 + k/3], {k, 0, 2}] + Log[3])]
     // Expand
(* 1/a^2 + Log[27]/(3 a) + PolyGamma[0, 1/3 + a]/(3 a) + 
   PolyGamma[0, 2/3 + a]/(3 a) - (2 PolyGamma[0, 1 + a])/(3 a) *)
```

Then, perform the outer `Sum`.  (Surprisingly, the simpler `Sum[%, {a, 1, p}]` returns unevaluated`.)

```
Sum[%[[1 ;; 2]], {a, 1, p}] + Sum[%[[3 ;; 5]], {a, 1, p}]
(* (3*HarmonicNumber[p, 2] + HarmonicNumber[p]*Log[27])/3 + 
   Sum[PolyGamma[0, 1/3 + a]/(3*a) + PolyGamma[0, 2/3 + a]/(3*a) - 
   (2*PolyGamma[0, 1 + a])/(3*a), {a, 1, p}] *)
```

Expanding the `First` term of this expression then gives the first part of the answer in the previous derivation,

```
Collect[Normal[Series[First[%], {p, Infinity, 1}]] /. p -> n/Sqrt[3], n, Simplify]
(* (-6 + Log[27])/(2 Sqrt[3] n) + 1/6 (π^2 + EulerGamma Log[729] 
   - Log[27] (Log[3] + 2 Log[1/n])) *)
```

and the `Last` term, the `Sum`, can be evaluated numerically, also as in the first derivation.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey : Thank you for your answer. I need some time to think about it.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey : Frankly speaking, I don't understand a big part of your code. Some transformations are done by hand, some ones are not based. Nevetherless, you obtain a quite simple result. I vote up your work, leaving its estimate for more skilled Mathematica users. Many thanks from me to you.

Comment: @user64494  The alternative derivation is much simpler and gives the same result.  I obtained it, because I too was uncomfortable with the complexity of the first derivation.